# Dynamically hiding tabs in SwiftUI TabView - Tabs mixed up in More... overflow item

Tags: swiftui

When you use an `if` statement in the SwiftUI TabView to dynamically hide/show tabs, SwiftUI will end up mixing up content in the 'More...' overflow tab item.

```swift
TabView() {
    if someCondition {
        View1()
    }
    View2()
    // ... more views
}
```

Steps to reproduce: Check out https://github.com/ralfebert/SwiftUITabItemOverflowBug , use the 'Show Moon' toggle which hides a tab. Go to the 'More...' overflow tab, and select 'trash'. This will now show the incorrect view - 'smoke' instead of the 'trash' one:

Seems like a SwiftUI bug (FB9078171). Is there a workaround to get the correct behaviour when dynamically showing and hiding tabs?

[image: incorrect tab shown]

Comment: Can you please update your question to include all relevant information, links to Github repos can expire.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
TabView() {
    if someCondition {
        View1()
    }
    View2()
    // ... more views
}
.id(someCondition)          // << here !!
```

Comment: Works for the example; although this has the side effect of resetting all @State/@StateObjects in all the tabs.

Comment: To avoid the reset, maybe try making your tab content EquatableViews? Here’s an explanation: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/01/22/optimizing-views-in-swiftui-using-equatableview/

Comment: This kinda works, but the animation on drag/swipe end is gone that way (using `PageTabViewStyle`)